# Derived structs vs structs pointing to other structs

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct

I wrote a function for a basic binary tree that has a node:

```
struct node{
  int key;
  node* left;
  node* right;
};
```

Now, for another class I would like to add pointers to predecessor and successors in this node. I am looking to be able to pass this new struct in as a node to the basic binary tree functions. As far as I understand from looking online, a derived struct cannot be passed in the place of its super. So, if I did:

```
struct fancyNode : public node{
  fancyNode* pred;
  fancyNode* succ;
};
```

this would not quite work.

My next idea was to just use a new struct with a pointer to the old node struct:

```
struct fancyNode{
  node* oldNode;
  fancyNode* pred;
  fancyNode* succ;
};
```

Now this would work, but I would have to pass that oldNode element to functions instead of being able to simply pass the whole fancyNode.

Is there another easier way I am missing or is this the only way to deal with this?

Comment: Can you describe how the first approach "would not quite work" and how the second approach requires the use of oldNode in the functions? What are the functions and what are the calls you are making?

Comment: "a derived struct cannot be passed in the place of its super". `fancyNode` cannot be passed to a function expecting `node` This is true, but `fancyNode` can be passed to a function expecting `node &` and `fancyNode *` can be passed to a function expecting `node *`. However,  `fancyNode` will be used by the latter two functions as a `node`. The  `fancyNode` extensions will not be available.

Comment: Ok.  I meant that the first approach would not quite work because of what @user4581301 said.  I thought that I might not be able to pass it into a function expecting node.  Most of my passes are actually `node *`, so it sounds like I can pass them.

Comment: Followup:  Say that I am making a 'node' in a BST insert function.  If I wanted to add the features of 'fancyNode' to that object later on, would that be possible in any way?  Or is the object set as 'node' permanently once it's created

Comment: "a derived struct cannot be passed in the place of its super" I believe a little reading about Polymorphisim may solve your problem, if you're willing: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pass by value vs. pass by reference**

> I understand from looking online, a derived struct cannot be passed in
>   the place of its super. So, (...) would not quite work.

This statement is correct if you intend to pass the objects by value.  [Slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) might then occur, so that you'd loose the additional data of the derived object.

However, you could certainly pass a pointer or a reference to a derived instead of a pointer or a reference to a base object.

**Polymorphism**

If you use struct the old C way, just to define a data structure that you would manipulated by some global functions, you would not benefit of C++'s object orientation.

You should think not of data structures, but of objects, that is data AND the operations that are usually performed on this data.  If you start design your code in this way, you could then make some operations polymorphic (using virtual functions). This would allow you not only to pass base and derived objects by pointers or references, but also invoke the basic operations without having to worry if its a base or a derived object.